# LINQ operator to split List of doubles to multiple list of double based on generic delimiter

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` double values in which some of the elements are NaN. I want to convert this list
into multiple list of doubles using NaN as delimiter.
Example:

```
List<double> values =  new List<double>        
   { 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, Double.NaN, 2.2, 2.3, Double.NaN, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 }; 
List<List<double>> result = values.SomeLinqOperator....
```

Comment: I have solution to do split. But it is lengthy. I wanted to see simpler way( one liner ) to do this using built-in LINQ operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<List<double>> result = values.GroupDelimited(x => x == double.NaN)
                                  .Select(g => g.ToList())
                                  .ToList();
```

using the *GroupDelimited Extension Method* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7418580/76217).

Answer (score 4):

Nothing built in, but you can write one:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitBy<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, T delimiter)
{
    List<T> buffer = new List<T>();
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(item, delimiter))
        {
            yield return buffer;
            buffer = new List<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.Add(item);
        }
    }
    yield return buffer;
}
static void Main()
{
    List<double> values = new List<double> 
        {1.2,2.2,3.2,double.NaN,2.2,2.3,double.NaN,4.1,4.2,4.3 };
    List<List<double>> result = values.SplitBy(double.NaN).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I have solution similar to yours, but its is lengthy. I wanted to see simpler way to do this using built in LINQ operator.

Comment: @madhu indeed, but there is no such built in operator

Answer (score 2):

This will include empty lists if you have two `double.NaN` values together, or one at the start or end of the input:

```
List<List<double>> result = new List<List<double>>();
List<double> current = new List<double>();
foreach (double d in values)
{
    if (d == double.NaN)
    {
        result.Add(current);
        current = new List<double>();
    }
    else
    {
        current.Add(d);
    }
}
result.Add(current);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler one (I think).

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T delimiter)
{
    EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (IEnumerable<T> s = source; s.Any(); s = s.SkipWhile(s2 => !comparer.Equals(s2, delimiter)).Skip(1))
        yield return s.TakeWhile(s2 => !comparer.Equals(s2, delimiter));
}
```