# Linq - List of List

Tags: linq

I have a list like the following

```
var stringCollection = {"X","1", "2","X","5", "10","X","7", "9"}
```

Now I need a List of List such that each sub list looks like the following

```
SibList1 = {"X","1", "2"}
SibList2 = {"X","5", "10"}
SibList3 = {"X","7", "9"}
```

Is it possible using linq.

Regards
Krish

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Comment: Is each sub list 3 elements, or can it vary, such as it just resets when you encounter an x again?

Comment: @sovemp either way there is a good enough duplicate : [LINQ operator to split List of doubles to multiple list of double based on generic delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194898/linq-operator-to-split-list-of-doubles-to-multiple-list-of-double-based-on-gener)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string[] stringCollection = { "X", "1", "2", "X", "5", "10", "X", "7", "9" };
int index = 0;
var subLists = stringCollection
    .Select(x => new { i = (x == "X" ? ++index : index), s = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.i)
    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.s).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Very clever, and a much better solution in my opinion  than the onegiven in the other post.